# Select correct app on connecting camera

Tags: photos

How do you prevent Apple Photos from opening on connecting a camera.

I prefer to download all my work to Lightroom 3.

Comment: Do you mean Photos launches whenever you log in to the Mac, or that Photos launches whenever you connect a camera/iPhone or insert a camera card?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Image Capture [in Applications] to dictate which photo app [or none at all] will open when you attach any photographic device, phone, camera, SD/CF card etc

I have mine set so that Image Capture itself launches when I insert a camera card, but ignores when my iPhone is connected.

[Drop menu artificially offset for visibility]

[image]

If you don't see the options at bottom left, click the little reveal icon, circled here in red.